# xpath expression for child elements

Tags: xpath

I have an xml file of this type

```
 <a Text="">
   <b>
     <c Text=""/>
     < c Text=""/>
   </b>
    <b>
          <c/>
    </b>
 </a>
```

So, I need an output like

```
     a
        c
        c
```

Can you please help me in the xpath expression for writing this? I need to ignore b from appearing.

Comment: Do you mean to find any descendant of <a> that is a <c> tag? Or do you mean that there is only ever one <b> tag and it contains <c> tags? Can you extend your question to show where a <c> tag might also show up, if there are <b> tags that don't have <c> tags, are there other types of tags that are children of <b>, etc. Based on what you have shown us, I wouldn't use xpath, I would just walk the document...

Comment: `//*[not(self::b)]` will select all nodes except of `b`.

Comment: @vansimke: the <a> tag and all <c> tags need to be selected. <C> tags will only occur inside <b>. There are no other c tags that occur individually

Answer (score 0):

Assumung you want so select a nodes and b nodes, you can use this expressions:

```
/a | /a/b/c
```

That will select all a nodes and (union) all c nodes. Note that it will only select them on the specified levels in your document. You can also go for something like:

```
//a | //c
```

Maybe you can give us some more info on the purpose of this query?

You can also you XQuery, like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
{
for $d in doc("test.xml")/a/b/c return
<a href="somepage.php?id={fn:data($d/@Text)}">{fn:data($d/@Text)}</a>
}
</div>
```

on the following input

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c Text="Cat1" />
    <c Text="Cat2" />
    <c Text="Cat3" />
  </b>
  <b>
    <c Text="Cat4" />
    <c Text="Cat5" />
  </b>
</a>
```

you will get this output:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="somepage.php?id=Cat1">Cat1</a>
    <a href="somepage.php?id=Cat2">Cat2</a>
    <a href="somepage.php?id=Cat3">Cat3</a>
    <a href="somepage.php?id=Cat4">Cat4</a>
    <a href="somepage.php?id=Cat5">Cat5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: SIte Navigation. When i clikc breadcrumb it needs to show up all the pages under it. In that process i dont want <b> tags to appear

Comment: I'm confused, why wouldn't the first option filter out the <c> tags that are outside of <b>?

Comment: I added an Xquery approach, can you use this?